# Bootstrap strange problem with column width / div positioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having a really difficult time trying to figure out *why* this is happening before I move further along in my development process of this page.

I have a very basic setup:

1. Fixed Footer
2. Fixed Header
3. A `col-lg-3` nav bar
4. A `col-lg-9` content box

The problem I am having is the `div` widths *inside* the nav `col-lg-3` are not taking up the full width of the parent `div`.  They appear to want to sit next to each other., even though I haven't declared a `float` -- and I have even tried `clear:both` between them.  The div with ID of `projects` is supposed to be **below** the div with ID `problem-div`  What am I doing wrong, or not understanding in order for this to happen?

**NOTE** The reason I am assuming this is a Bootstrap issue, is because if I remove the links to the CDN, the `html` / `css` functions as expected.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  color: #ED6F2B;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#info-column {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
}

#map-column {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #93E7ED;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="header">
  HEADER
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">

  <div id="info-column" class="col-lg-3">
    <div id="problem-div" class="text-center">
      <div>
        <a href="//example.com"><img style="width:45%" alt="" src="logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>THIS PERSON'S COMPANY AND SERVICES</h2>
      </div>
      <div>(555) 555-5555</div>
      <div>person@thispersonscompanyandservices.com</div>
      <div><a href="//example.com">thispersonscompanyandservices.com</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
       PROJECTS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map-column" class="col-lg-9">
    MAP CONTENT
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  FOOTER
</div>
```

Comment: Do you not want the sub items of `#info-column` to be flex items?

Comment: @BSMP Sorry .. I have tried to make them `flex` items and it doesn't behave as expected either ..  I have no issues with them being flex items.

Comment: Well first, you are not using the Bootstrap grid system correctly... you have columns with no rows. Please read the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works) ... _In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows._

Comment: @zgood  I have read the docs, and the way I understand it, is that your `column`s are *inside* each `row` --  Correct?  I have tried setting a class of `row` to the main wrapper, as there is really only one row .. I can re-insert that into the snippet, but it responds the same.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: the `info-column` is set to display:flex and the default direction is row

Comment: @Temani Afif exactly what I was looking for ..  Please write an answer explaining why flex overwrote bootstrap, and I will accept and vote +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not bootstrap related. If you remove it you will get the same issue:

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  color: #ED6F2B;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#info-column {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
}

#map-column {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #93E7ED;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  HEADER
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">

  <div id="info-column" class="col-lg-3">
    <div id="problem-div" class="text-center">
      <div>
        <a href="//example.com"><img style="width:45%" alt="" src="logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>THIS PERSON'S COMPANY AND SERVICES</h2>
      </div>
      <div>(555) 555-5555</div>
      <div>person@thispersonscompanyandservices.com</div>
      <div><a href="//example.com">thispersonscompanyandservices.com</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
       PROJECTS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map-column" class="col-lg-9">
    MAP CONTENT
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  FOOTER
</div>
```

And this is due to the use of `display:flex` within `#info-column`. The default direction is row making both child divs next to each other. Switch to a column direction or simply remove `display:flex`

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  color: #ED6F2B;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#info-column {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
}

#map-column {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #93E7ED;
  margin-top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(100% - 140px);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  HEADER
</div>

<div class="main-wrapper">

  <div id="info-column" class="col-lg-3">
    <div id="problem-div" class="text-center">
      <div>
        <a href="//example.com"><img style="width:45%" alt="" src="logo.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>THIS PERSON'S COMPANY AND SERVICES</h2>
      </div>
      <div>(555) 555-5555</div>
      <div>person@thispersonscompanyandservices.com</div>
      <div><a href="//example.com">thispersonscompanyandservices.com</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
       PROJECTS
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map-column" class="col-lg-9">
    MAP CONTENT
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  FOOTER
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer .. I did not "see" flex overwriting the rows ..  Seems I was too close to the problem.  Thanks again.